# How to implement better

Tags: c#, oop, enums

I create a service, which get some information from different APIs. Each API works with language list, some language are common, some are individual for concrete API. I create an Interface with universal methods to call API.

```
public interface IOCR
{
    Task<OCRResult> GetTextAsync(string fileUrl, Language language);
}
```

where language is enum like:

```
public enum Language
{
    Chinese_Simplified,
    Chinese_Traditional,
    Danish,
    Dutch,
    ....
}
```

but first API has also Russian, second API German for example. How to implement it correctly?

Option 1:
Create full list of all languages. But then client application does not know whether the language is supported or not.

Option 2:
Pass simple string instead of enum. But then we should know which strings are valid for concrete API.

It would be good with base enum and then pass inherited enum, but enums does not allow inheritance

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `GetTextAsync`, also add another method in your interface named `GetLanguages` that returns a `Language[]` so the caller could ask the API about the languages supported by it at runtime. This has the added benefit of easily extending your APIs in the future without making any modifications on the service end.

Comment: 1. No API method to return language list, just "hard-coded" list in the documentation, 2. Then you propose to pass string as parameter? How to prevent to send unsupported value?

Comment: @OlegSh: Since this interface will be implemented by YOU on the client end, you can include `GetLanguages` in the interface and implement it in the concrete classes you create for each API, wherein you can hard-code all the Language values after reading them from the documentation. You do not need to do it as `strings`, just use your enum as the return type of this new function.

Comment: ok, but my enum is "common", I need a "base" enum, which will be implemented as returned value of the method GetLanguages.... How to implement it with enum?

Comment: You don't need a base `enum`. Just use your `Language` enum everywhere. Before calling `GetTextAsync`, you simply call `GetLanguages` and make sure that the enum value u want to pass actually exists in the returned array. Similarly if you're asking your user to choose a language, you simply supply the list of supported languages in a UI element (such a combobox) by populating it with the array returned by `GetLanguages()` for the selected API.

Comment: in this case we add pre-condition (GetLanguages should be called before GetTextAsync), I don't like such relationships. Client of class should know it, he can forget about it etc...